# Connecting mongodb with postgres SQL

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, postgresql, mongoose

I have a post schema in mongodb. example:

```
 const Post = new Schema(
  {
    user_id: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },  
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
    },
    attached_files: [IdeaMedia],
    status: {
      type: Number,
      default: 1,
      enum: Object.values(IdeaStatus), // 0- inactive, 1- active, 2- delete
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: { createdAt: "created_at", updatedAt: "updated_at" },
  }
);
```

And I have a user table in postgres sql. Example: ( I am using sequelize ORM)

```
const UserSchema = sequelize.db.define(
  "user",
  {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    first_name: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    last_name: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    avatar: {
      type: STRING,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    phone: BIGINT,
    email: {
      type: STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
      set(value) {
        this.setDataValue("email", value.trim().toLowerCase());
      },
    },
    status: {
      type: INTEGER,
      defaultValue: 1,
      validate: {
        isIn: {
          args: [[0, 1, 2]],
          msg: "Invalid Status Value",
        },
      },
    },
  },
  {
    tableName: "user",
    createdAt: "created_at",
    updatedAt: "updated_at",
  }
);
```

Now I want to fetch list of posts (Posts from different users). Is there any way connect both the database?

I know I can store more then user_id in Post schema like first_name, last_name, avatar but what if a user has updated their avatar or first_name then I will have to update all the post which belongs to this user. Which is not feasible. So, Is there any way to connect this two table? Or should I try another way to do this?

I also know that I can use a single database either postgres or mongodb to store user and post but I want to know if this can be possible or not.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Using two databases is not uncommon, but using them for relational data across each other is unwise.

But first, an answer to your question:

- Get the full list of Posts from MongoDB
- Create a second list by using `Array.map()` to get all the unique values of `user_id` together
- Get the users' data from Postgres using the array of IDs ^
- Combine all the results appropriately

Somewhat of an example (very pseudo, adapt according to your project of course)

```
// array of Post objects
const posts = getPostsFromMongo();
const userIds = posts.map(post => {
    return post.user_id;
});
// use Set() to only return unique IDs
const userIdSet = new Set(userIds);

// array of User objects
const users = getUsersFromPostgres(userIdSet);
```

Few different ways to combine, here are two choices:

##### `User` object added as new `userInfo` property

```
const combined = posts.map(post => {
    post.userInfo = users.find(user => {
        return user.id === post.user_id;
    });
    return post;
});
```

##### `User` object data spread across at the same level as `Post` (prefixed with "user_" since some fields conflict

```
const combined = posts.map(post => {
    const userInfo = users.find(user => {
        return user.id === post.user_id;
    });
    return {
        ...post,
        user_first_name: userInfo.first_name,
        user_last_name: userInfo.last_name,
        user_avatar: userInfo.avatar,
        user_status: userInfo.status,
        // ... rest of userInfo, except "id" since it already exists as Post.user_id (and assuming Post.id exists, would also conflict with that)
    };
});
```

---

I still recommend **against** this DB arrangement.

The most immediate reason is your two DBs will not provide referential integrity between each other (so `user_id` in Mongo may be pointing to a row that no longer exists in Postgres).  If you want to use them both, make one (recommend Postgres) the PRIMARY and use logical replication to stream all updates live to the SECONDARY DB.

The second reason is to have a single source of truth (which you maybe aren't *not* doing currently, but does not appear likely).  Once both DBs have the same data (from replication), you only access from one (Mongo) when reading data.

A good example of how something like this is done in practice is with [Debezium](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/2.1/connectors/mongodb.html)